# FFMPEG progress bar in java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, progress-bar

Is there a way I can get the FFMPEG progress bar like this [ffmpeg-progress bar](http://www.prupert.co.uk/2010/05/11/finally-a-bash-progress-indicator-for-ffmpeg-that-works/comment-page-1/#comment-618)
in java or at least use the script shown in the link to work in my Java file?

Comment: You can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43087690/1759327) but its for Android

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BSD-licensed [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) library to enable advanced console features. The class [`jline.Terminal`](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jline/Terminal.html) allows you to clear and re-draw the current line of text.